# How To Create a Unique Key For A Dictionary In Python

Tags: python, hash, dictionary

What is the best way to generate a unique key for the contents of a dictionary. My intention is to store each dictionary in a document store along with a unique id or hash so that I don't have to load the whole dictionary from the store to check if it exists already or not. *Dictionaries with the same keys and values should generate the same id or hash.*

I have the following code:

```
import hashlib

a={'name':'Danish', 'age':107}
b={'age':107, 'name':'Danish'}

print str(a)
print hashlib.sha1(str(a)).hexdigest()
print hashlib.sha1(str(b)).hexdigest()
```

The last two print statements generate the same string. Is this is a good implementation? or are there any pitfalls with this approach? Is there a better way to do this?

**Update**

Combining suggestions from the answers below, the following might be a good implementation

```
import hashlib

a={'name':'Danish', 'age':107}
b={'age':107, 'name':'Danish'}


def get_id_for_dict(dict):
    unique_str = ''.join(["'%s':'%s';"%(key, val) for (key, val) in sorted(dict.items())])
    return hashlib.sha1(unique_str).hexdigest()

print get_id_for_dict(a)
print get_id_for_dict(b)
```

Comment: Your implementation in update is very wrong: try this: `get_id_for_dict({'foo':'bar'})` or `get_id_for_dict({'fo':'obar'})` or `get_id_for_dict({'f':'o','o':'bar'})`. They all return `8843d7f92416211de9ebb963ff4ce28125932878`. Better use  `unique_str = join(['%s%s'%(hashlib.sha1(key), hashlib.sha1(val)) for (key, val) in sorted(dict.items())])`

Comment: @Tometzky Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I tried your suggestion, but it fails if keys or values are not of type string. Instead, I just changed the string format to enclose key & value in quotes and put a colon character between them

Comment: Still not good if there can be a `'`, `:` and `;` in key or value. Use `unique_str = join(['%s%s'%(hashlib.sha1(str(key)), hashlib.sha1(str(val))) for (key, val) in sorted(dict.items())])`

Comment: Can you provide an example where the current implementation would not work?

Comment: `{'b':"ar';'f':'oo"}` and `{'b':'ar','f':'oo'}` would both get the same `unique_str`: `'b':'ar';'f':'oo';` and the same hash

Comment: @Tometzky Nice work with the examples! I guess I was not expecting such patterns in my data. *However*, your suggestion generates a different id for the *same* dicts every time I execute the code. The following seems to work though `unique_str = ''.join(['%s%s'%(hashlib.sha1(str(key)).hexdigest(), hashlib.sha1(str(val)).hexdigest()) for (key, val) in sorted(dict.items())])`. Does this follow the Python spirit of doing things? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible option would be using a serialized representation of the list that preserves order. I am not sure whether the default list to string mechanism imposes any kind of order, but it wouldn't surprise me if it were interpreter-dependent. So, I'd basically build something akin to `urlencode` that sorts the keys beforehand.

Not that I believe that you method would fail, but I'd rather play with predictable things and avoid undocumented and/or unpredictable behavior. It's true that despite "unordered", dictionaries end up having an order that may even be consistent, but the point is that you shouldn't take that for granted.

Comment: I appologize, I wasn't clear. My intention is that Dictionaries with the same keys and values should generate the same id or hash

Comment: -1.  From my reading of the question the unique identifier should be based on the contents of the dictionary.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Pedro answered before I added my clarification in the question.

Comment: @Pedro Ferreira:  From the urlencode doc "The order of parameters in the encoded string will match the order of parameter tuples in the sequence."  Unfortunately, this order can vary for identical dictionaries.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, I said "something akin to `urlencode` that sorts the keys beforehand". **Not** `urlencode`.

Comment: @Pedro Ferreira:  Remove the incorrect part of your answer (the `uuid` part) and I'll remove my downvote.  The remaining part of your answer is substandard.

Answer (score 41):

I prefer serializing the dict as JSON and hashing that:

```
import hashlib
import json

a={'name':'Danish', 'age':107}
b={'age':107, 'name':'Danish'}

# Python 2
print hashlib.sha1(json.dumps(a, sort_keys=True)).hexdigest()
print hashlib.sha1(json.dumps(b, sort_keys=True)).hexdigest()

# Python 3
print(hashlib.sha1(json.dumps(a, sort_keys=True).encode()).hexdigest())
print(hashlib.sha1(json.dumps(b, sort_keys=True).encode()).hexdigest())
```

Returns:

```
71083588011445f0e65e11c80524640668d3797d
71083588011445f0e65e11c80524640668d3797d
```

Comment: Thanks! This is an elegant solution indeed, which takes care of differentiating between `{'b':"ar';'f':'oo"}` and `{'b':'ar','f':'oo'}` as well.

Answer (score 7):

No - [you can't rely on particular order of elements when converting dictionary to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289418/is-the-python-dict-str-function-reliably-sorting-keys).

You can, however, convert it to sorted list of (key,value) tuples, convert it to a string and compute a hash like this:

```
a_sorted_list = [(key, a[key]) for key in sorted(a.keys())]
print hashlib.sha1( str(a_sorted_list) ).hexdigest()
```

It's not fool-proof, as a formating of a list converted to a string or formatting of a tuple can change in some future major python version, sort order depends on locale etc. but I think it can be good enough.

Comment: Better would be to use `sorted(a.items())`, then you can collapse this to a one-liner without loss of readability.