# How to make a list of the lowest number among each month in .csv without python module?

Tags: python

I am trying to list out the minimal number of ticket sold sorting by the month.

```
csv_file = open(csvfile,"r")
    
date_and_ticket = []
for data in csv_file:
    data = data.replace('\n','').split(',')
    date_and_ticket.append(data[0:2])
            
print(date_and_ticket)
```

From here, I am able to sort out the result like this:

```
[['16/3/20', '9'], ['17/3/20', '4'], ['18/4/20', '4'], ['19/1/20', '5'], ['17/6/20', '89'], ['18/6/20', '104'], ['19/6/20', '128'], ['20/1/20', '79']]
```

However, I would like to sort the data according to their months in chronological order and add the value zero if the month is not in the list.

This is what I hope to do:

```
[5,0,4,4,0,89,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

and here is the small portion of the .csv
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aqMwZcSzbY8WpeyTzXP76Sl46acO23bI/view?usp=sharing

Any advice would be greatly appreciated thank you! :)

Comment: What do you mean by `add the value zero if the month is not in the list`? Which list are you referring to?

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Your posted code simply reads the CSV file into a list, which is irrelevant to your question.    Simply assigning that data to `date_and_ticket` has the same effect for your question.  You need to analyze the problem into its processing steps.  Then learn the language tools appropriate to the problem -- in this case, `PANDAS` and `datetime` will do the job.  Extract the month, use `groupby` on those, and take the minimum of each group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `dict.setdefault` to create monthly values:

```
l = [['16/3/20', '9'], ['17/3/20', '4'], ['18/4/20', '4'], 
     ['19/1/20', '5'], ['17/6/20', '89'], ['18/6/20', '104'], 
     ['19/6/20', '128'], ['20/1/20', '79']]

res = {}
for d, v in l:
    month = int(d.split("/")[1])
    res.setdefault(month, []).append(int(v))
```

Output:

```
{1: [5, 79], 3: [9, 4], 4: [4], 6: [89, 104, 128]}
```

Then `dict.get` to make 0 for absent months:

```
[min(res.get(i, [0])) for i in range(1, 13)]
```

Output:

```
[5, 0, 4, 4, 0, 89, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I never think of using dictionary to solve this. Thanks a lot bro!

Comment: How did you sort the key value in chronological order to show result in output 1?

Comment: @DiaryWolf If you want the `dict` to be sorted, you will have to sort the `l` beforehand or sort the `res` afterward. The output 1 is just mere coincidence made from `print`. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289418/is-the-python-dict-str-function-reliably-sorting-keys. `print`ing `dict` _may_ seem to sort it, but it really does not.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org).

Read your `csv` in a `Pandas Dataframe`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
```

Your `df` will look like:

```
In [1190]: df
Out[1190]: 
      date ticket_sold
0  16/3/20           9
1  17/3/20           4
2  18/4/20           4
3  19/1/20           5
4  17/6/20          89
5  18/6/20         104
6  19/6/20         128
7  20/1/20          79

 # Convert `date` column to datetime and extract month
In [1196]: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.month

 # Groupby `month` and pick minimum tickets_sold per month
In [1203]: x = df.groupby('date')['ticket_sold'].min()

In [1208]: import numpy as np

# Fill data for missing months with 0    
In [1207]: output = x.reindex(np.arange(1,13)).fillna(0).astype(int).values.tolist()

In [1209]: output
Out[1207]: [5, 0, 4, 4, 0, 89, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```